# Add CSS to python script

Tags: python, css

I am currently trying to use python to query a MySQL database and output the results on a local webpage (running on a RaspPi) and it all works well so far. The code below outputs the data as expected in a table.

However, I would like to use CSS to style my table to avoid inline styling.

Just like you can put PHP, HTML and CSS in one file, I would like to do the same with Python. Is that possible without using any framework like Django?

Many thanks in advance!

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()

#Connect to the database.
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
    db='mydb',
    user='myuser',
    passwd='mypw',
    host='localhost')
c = conn.cursor()

# Print the contents of the database.
c.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")

strHtml = """<html>
    <table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' style='border: 0.5px solid black ;'><thead>
      <tr>
         <th style='border: 1px solid black;'><ins>userName</ins></th>
         <th style='border: 1px solid black;'><ins>userEmail</ins></th>
         <th style='border: 1px solid black;'><ins>name</ins></th>
         <th style='border: 1px solid black;'><ins>surname</ins></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>"""


for r in c.fetchall():    
    strHtml += "<tr><td style='border: 0.5px solid black;'>" + r[1] + "</td>"
    strHtml += "<td style='border: 0.5px solid black;'>" + r[2] + "</td>"
    strHtml += "<td style='border: 0.5px solid black;'>" + r[3] + "</td>"
    strHtml += "<td style='border: 0.5px solid black;'>" + r[4] + "</td></tr>" 


strHtml += "</tbody></table></html>"

print(strHtml)

c.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: How are you accessing this output as a web page now?  Looks like this just prints the html to the console.

Comment: I think what you want is a templating engine. `Jinja2` is a very popular one in the Python world. I would recommend reading the docs and using it to build and render a template with what you want: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/intro/#basic-api-usage

Comment: Thank your for the answers :) I am just calling the python script by its name @erewok: that looks promising, I'll have a look into it, thanks :)

Comment: It worked!! Made my day, thank you so much, erewok.